# Removing duplicates from a file in real-time when the file is been populated

Tags: python, json

I am using Python and want to share my problem if anyone has encountered a similar one. I am trying to solve my problem before writing the code. (Think twice, write once.)

Assume I have a file `outfile_1.json` which is populated every 0.5 seconds with data from an external web source, all in realtime. How do I remove duplicates in realtime assuming another program reads the file `outfile_1.json` and remove duplicates?

My idea is this:

1. Read first 100 lines outfile_1.json from bottom and remove
   duplicates
2. Keep a record of how many duplicates was removed
3. Move to a location in the file from 100 - total_removed_lines + 100. That
   is, we have 100 lines at hand left with 90 after 10 duplicates. Next
   start line would be line 90.
4. We repeat 1 to 3 in a while loop until 6 p.m. when our program stops.

I'm sure the above would fail at some point, but I am not sure how and when so I am thinking if someone could advise with some pseudo code or define a better approach.

**This is a sample copy of a JSON file: Notice first and second are same so 1 must be removed.**

```
{"price": "$195.57", "volume": "100", "tradetime": "10:51:03", "timeframe": "3", "date": "09-21-2015", "symbol": "DIP"}
{"price": "$195.57", "volume": "100", "tradetime": "10:51:03", "timeframe": "3", "date": "09-21-2015", "symbol": "DIP"}
{"price": "$193.52", "volume": "100", "tradetime": "10:51:03", "timeframe": "3", "date": "09-21-2015", "symbol": "DIP"}
{"price": "$197.59", "volume": "131", "tradetime": "10:51:03", "timeframe": "3", "date": "09-21-2015", "symbol": "DIP"}
{"price": "$197.58", "volume": "300", "tradetime": "10:51:02", "timeframe": "3", "date": "09-21-2015", "symbol": "DIP"}
{"price": "$197.58", "volume": "100", "tradetime": "10:51:01", "timeframe": "3", "date": "09-21-2015", "symbol": "DIP"}
```

Comment: Why don't you readjust to avoid writing duplicates to the file in the first place? Or remove them all at the end of the day? Having two programs (potentially) simultaneously accessing the same file is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: I don't get the question tbh. Just read and remove duplicate using one and only instance of the code? why read first 100 lines only? why not all lines?

Comment: @jonrsharpe read and remove duplicates in realtime. Because while duplicates are been removed more item are added to the json file which means possible duplicates been added, file size changing. etc.

Comment: ...you realise those are arguments *for* what I'm suggesting, right?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I suspect that what he's not expressing well is that he does not control the external web source.  jide, is this correct?

Comment: That still leaves post-processing to remove the dupes; if you're not even controlling the other program that could be accessing the file, you're in for a world of hurt.

Comment: Will the OS allow two different programs to have the file open in write mode at the same time? If so, I see big trouble ahead.

Comment: Someone said: downvoting only for the sake of for personal rep gain. Now that is anti-community.

Answer (score 0):

Are the existing entries a hashable type?  If not, just convert each to its string image.  You can use the entire line as the key to a dictionary or element of a set.  Call that "reference".
Keep that set active.  Then, just compare each of the 100 new lines to "reference" with a simple "in" check.

Let the new batch of entries be a list of strings called "new_batch".

```
dup_count = 0
new_count = 0
for line in new_batch:
    if line in reference:
        dup_count += 1
    else:
        new_count += 1
        reference += line   # ... or however you add a new element to this object

print dup_count, "duplicates removed"
print new_count, "new elements"
```

I trust that you can make proper use of new_count and dup_count from here.